# Scaling Terracota - Free and Open Source?

Tags: ehcache, terracotta, distributed-cache

Is Terracota ehcache scaling across various nodes open source or is it a commercial product? Apparently, it did not require a commercial licence earlier but it does now.

From http://ehcache.org/ - "For applications requiring a coherent distributed cache as well as in-memory performance, use Terracotta BigMemory Max which is available in both extended trial and full versions. (Terracotta no longer actively updates the open-source version of Terracotta Server Array, also known as Terracotta.)"

Can someone throw some light on it? I find confusing information on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The open source Terracotta is defunct. The team behind it is also gone. But EHCache itself is open source.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?